# Writing to CSV, not every element is being appended to file

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I am using beautifulsoup to find all instances of a class within a webpage, however...

As I try to write it to a CSV file

```
soup_string = str(element.get_text())
with open('finallist.csv', mode='a') as final_list:
    stock_writer = csv.writer(final_list, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    stock_writer.writerow([ticker, defunct.text])
```

It's only writing one item into the CSV, as [so.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoyR6.png)

This is despite the actual output being [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOG0q.png)

Comment: Do you have a sample of the data which you are trying to write to the CSV file? My guess would be that you need to loop through all the items in a list of data, thus, you are only writing one row.

Comment: Using beautifulsoup I'm gathering all of a class matching _20mbifX838(site:OTCMarkets.com)

defunct = soup.find_all("a", ("_20mbifX838"))

Comment: Sorry, forgot to notify you, @JacobLee

Comment: What is `defunct`?  How is that image made?  What does the csv file contain?

Comment: As Jacob said, the code you have posted writes exactly one row to a CSV, and the row it writes has nothing to do with soup_string.  If you expect help, you need to show us the context.  Is this in a loop?  Show us the loop.

Comment: Sure. I'm pretty sure I've shown all that's relevant but I suppose if I knew that, I wouldn't be here!

with open("CleanedWL.txt", "r") as file:

    first_line = file.readline()
options = Options()
options.headless = True
ticker = first_line
stringurl = "https://www.otcmarkets.com/stock/"+ticker+"/overview" #Inserts first line into the URL
url = stringurl 
chrome_driver_path = ''
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
html_source = browser.page_source  
browser.quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source)  

That's the rest of the code you haven't yet seen. @TimRoberts

Comment: If that's all the code, then why do you expect multiple lines in your CSV?  You're only writing one line.

Answer (score 0):

if you use `.find_all()` you have too loop because it ResultSet object that may contains multiple element.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'html.parser')
defunct = soup.find_all("a", ("_20mbifX838"))

with open('finallist.csv', mode='a') as final_list:
    stock_writer = csv.writer(final_list, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for element in defunct:
        stock_writer.writerow([ticker, element.text])
```